# Help understanding 意味で in these sentences?

Tags: meaning

> いろんな意味で正月をむかえた感じがしたよ
>
> いろんな意味でご名算な気がしたよ

Context (if needed):

The speaker is trying to expose a robot pretending to be human.  The first line is said when the robot ends up pouring soup from her thermos (instead of engine oil).  The second line is said when the robot ends up attempting to use an abacus and hand calculations (instead of using an in-built calculator).

My attempt:

I had a feeling New Year is coming in various significance (??)

I feel like my interpretation of 意味 is wrong, and I'm not sure if で is the "by/in" particle or て form of です.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 意味 refers to the "sense" or "meaning" of a word/phrase, and いろんな意味 refers to various meanings, or usages, of a word/phrase.

To take a simpler example, いろんな意味で熱かった (literally "It was *hot* in various senses/meanings") means something was both exciting and physically in high temperature. いろんな意味でヤバい means something is crazy/insane both in the positive sense ("cool") and in the negative sense ("awful").

Regarding いろんな意味でご名算, ご名算 is a fixed phrase used in abacus lessons, meaning "(your answer is) correct". So one meaning is "your calculation result is correct". The second meaning is probably "your **way** of calculation is amazing/surprising". The kanji 名 can mean "awesome", as in 名言.

It's hard to explain いろんな意味で正月をむかえた with the provided context. If this soup is [*zōni*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z%C5%8Dni), one meaning is straightforward ("Zōni was served and I felt as if a new year had come"). There must be one more thing that is associated with 正月 in the story.

Comment: Regarding 正月, I understand my question gives insufficient context for this.I didn't notice anything related to it in the prior chapters when I wrote the question.  Just now, I tried to watch the anime adaptation and it's mentioned that "Spring has arrived - A new year has begun."  Maybe the context will be more clear to me as I continue reading.   You've already comprehensively answered the question I asked.

Answer (score 1):

If the robot is pretending to be human, the robot must be feeling the sense like human(i.e. pouring soup from the thermos or doing calculation with abacus)

So, this 意味 seems to mean "sense" here.

Thus, "In various sense, I feel the new year arriving." for いろんな意味で正月をむかえた感じがしたよ and "In various sense, I feel it is the precise calculation." for いろんな意味でご名算な気がしたよ.

This で seems to match "in" preposition to indicate circumstances and it is irrelevant to です: polite form.

Comment: In which meaning are you using this "sense"? In English, "sense" means both "meaning (of a word)" and "perception", and by looking at the first sentence of your answer, I feel you are talking about human-like perception (触覚, 視覚, ...). However, 意味 never refers to that.

Comment: @naruto ん、どういう意味ですか。なんか、文脈に引っ張られて私が墓穴を掘った感じですか。もっと抽象的な感覚や感情について言っているという事ですか。ロボットが人間のようなセンサーを持っているからこそ、水筒からスープを注いだりやそろばんを弾いているのかなと。

Comment: あなたの回答の1文目と2文目を素直に読むと「意味」という日本語は「センサーが感じるもの」「感覚」という意味だ、と言っているように思えるのですが、という話です。日本語では「意味」と「感覚」は全く違う単語ですよね。英語の "sense" には「言葉の意味」と「感覚」の両方の意味があるので混乱しないように語らないといけないのですが、どうもこの回答の途中でその辺がごっちゃになってしまっている気がします。

Comment: @naruto 言い換えると、「どう言う意味だ？」と「変な感覚だな。」は内観的に全く違うと言う事でしょうか？主体が内包している脳内に現れる思惟の対象として浮かんでくる内容としては、つまり印象としてはそこまで違わないかなと思うのですが。すみません、edit見てなかったです、確かに分析出来ていなかったので、結果的に端折ったかも知れないです。narutoさんの説明に問題があるとは思っていません。やや複雑かなとは思います。